# Prove that that it is a semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

Given the semigroup $(S,*)$ with at least two elements such that for every $x$ and $y$ in $S$ it holds that $x*y^{2}*x=x^2$ let us look at structure $(S,×) $ where operation "$×$" is defined as $x×y=y^2*x$. Prove that $(S,×)$ is a semigroup and check whether it can be a group.

I'm kind of stuck with this problem, it's obvious that closure holds, but I'm stuck to prove that it's associative, I got that $(x×y)×z = z^2*y^2*x$ and $x×(y×z) = z^4*y^2*x$. I don't know what I can do to apply that given condition here. And since I didn't even prove it is associative I have no idea if it can be a group.

Comment: Ohhhh now I see, using that condition, we get that z^4 = z^2

Comment: Regardless of that, it seems I calculated it wrong, second equation shouldn't have z^4, when I was squaring I forgot that commutative law doesn't have to hold in a semigroup. So I solved it after that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: To prove associativity, simply use the associativity of $*$ (and the axiom $xy^2x=x^2$). You do *not* need the observation that the condition implies that $x^2=x^4$ for all $x$ for this.

To check whether it can be a group show that it cannot have a neutral element (if it has more than one element). To that end, suppose suppose $\times$ has a (two sided!) neutral element $e$. Deduce that for all $x\in S$, you have $x=e^3$. Then notice that $e^3=e$.